# Google INSTALL_REFERRER "not set" on the tablets

Tags: android, install-referrer

I faced with problem. I have BroadcatReceiver which gets the utm_source from Google Play.

Manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".utils.referring.InstallReferrerReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Alpha version of my app in Google Play. When I was testing my app I got utm_source from phones correctly (Samsung, Xiaomi, Huawei), but when I tried to test using tablets (Samsung, Nexus) I saw that my utm_source value equals not_set.

What is the problem?

Comment: any solution to that ?